# Helping Finding A friend bot

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

My friend has a discord server called Find A Friend and he wants me to code a bot to type a command to ask a series of questions and put it in a channel. People can see if anybody interests them and becomes friends with them. I have already coded part of it.

One of the questions it asks is: What games do you like?

My friend wants to make it able that the bot searches the other answers to this same question and dm the user if they have a game in common. I want to do the same for another question: What are some shows, movies, and anime that you like?

Here is my code for the series of questions:

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "faf",
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete()
        const questions = [
            "What is your usernames for any games you have including discord (is fine if you dont put them all but you MUST include your discord)",
            "What is your age (not required)",
            "What is your gender",
            "Do you talk in Voicechannel or through text?",
            "What games do you like?",
            "What are some shows, movies, and anime that you like",
            "Where are you from (not required)",
            "Please state anything else you want to say"

        ]

        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        const appStart = await message.author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
        const channel = appStart.channel;

        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);

        collector.on("collect", () => {
           if(collectCounter < questions.length)  {
               channel.send(questions[collectCounter++])
           } else {
               channel.send('Your Find A Friend thread has been sent, Good Luck!')
               collector.stop("fulfilled");
           }
        });

        const appsChannel = client.channels.cache.get("831292911437086760");
        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if(reason === 'fulfilled') {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected
                .map((msg) => {
                    return `${index++}) ${questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`;
                }).join('\n\n')

                appsChannel.send(
                    new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(
                        message.author.tag, 
                        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
                    )
                    .setTitle('Friend Thread')
                    .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                    .setColor('RED')
                    .setTimestamp()
                )
            }

        });
    },
};
```

---

TL;DR I currently have a message collector bot that records responses to questions. How can I make the bot recognize when two people share common interests, such as games, movies, shows, or anime, based on their responses?

Comment: How to code a bot to find anyone who has the same anwsers to the application system i coded and dm the user that someone has the same anwser as you

Comment: accidenttly removed your comment sorry